# Experimental tips RC second order circuit

Tags: filter

I'm implementing a RC second order filter in the lab. My results were quite good, but of course not exactly equal to the simulation and theoretical prediction. I'm trying to understand why this is happening. I came up with a few points:

1. the components are not exactly their nominal value. They have tolerances associated to them that will obviously affect the pole localization and the gain.
2. some measurements, specially using the oscilloscope, have some errors associated with them: systematic ones, related to the precision of the instruments, and aleatory ones related errors reading the values or placing the cursors.
3. there is low frequency noise component caused by the presence of lamps. That noise will affect the measurements at low frequency.
4. there is also noise caused by the wires.

Any more tips about things that might affect our measurements?

Comment: How exact/inexact in both cases do you mean?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to help you without seeing your schematic for both simulation and measurement.

Comment: Also imperfections of the IC (if you're using one) which gives finite input/output impedance, improperly filtered supply, imperfect source, take your pick.

Comment: Non-linearities in the components, intermodulation products.

Comment: Capacitor ESR could affect it.